# Why is "does" sometimes pronounced "is"?

Tags: pronunciation

I'm watching a movie at the moment and I came across something that I've always found strange in the English language.

In some questions, mostly something like "What does he look like?", the *does* is pronounced *is*, so it sounds like "What is he look like?".

EDIT: The example from the movie [Click here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B1TeD7LxKfCFbm1Sd1c4SG0yTTg/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 20):

This is a combination of two phonetic effects. First, final /t/ and initial /d/ often merge into a tap [ɾ] when the second word is unstressed. You probably know this sound from the general American pronunciation of “city” [sɪɾi].

Second, because of the [weak vowel merger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_English_high_front_vowels#Weak-vowel_merger) in many accents, *is* and *does* can have the same vowel, freely varying in pronunciation between schwa /ə/ and short I /ɪ/.

The net effect is that “what does” can be pronounced [wʌɾɪz], and be differentiated from “what is” only by context. Luckily, the two phrases are used differently, so in practice it’s easy to know what was meant.

Comment: Also for *what has*, as in “What’s he done now?”

Comment: Would it be correct to write so too? Use *is* instead of *does*?

Comment: @camelbrush You could write it as "what's" in informal register, but not as "what is".

Comment: @Zack can you please quote a source/resource that depicts using *what's* acceptable over *what does* ?

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Yes, I've never found it to be difficult to differentiate between the two meaning, but it was a bit irritating and that's why I asked. Thanks again for this very scientific answer ;)

Answer (score 7):

*What’s* is probably what you heard. This can be short for *what is* but also for *what does*.

Comment: There's also a two-syllable variant ['wəɾɨz] that represents *either _what is_ or _what does_, because the /t/ of _what is_ and the /td/ cluster of _what does_ both reduce to [ɾ] between a stressed and an unstressed vowel, like _latter/ladder_. Clusters in auxiliary verb trains are almost always reduced, since they're predictable and therefore disposable in speech.

Answer (score 6):

It does sound like ***"What is..."*** when that particular group of words is run together and here is why I think that happens.  To pronounce "what does" properly, you would need to open your mouth twice, once for the  a in what, again for the o in does.  There are also two hard consonants, back-to-back between these two vowels. Native speakers will slur together the two words, avoiding the second hard consonant, skipping directly to the "s" of "does", resulting in  something that sounds like ***waduz*** - which is probably being heard as ***"what is"***. (At least that's what happens when I say ***"what does"*** quickly.)

Comment: Kristina, I think you're basically right in your description of how and why this happens, but I also think the resulting word quite often actually is said with an "i" sound, like "wudiz." (I knonw I do this myself.) It's not merely "waduz" being misheard.

Comment: @JohnM.Landsberg, I can reproduce what the OP reported hearing but my transcription is lacking.  It's actually somewhere between a short "u" and a short "i" but I think you're right, too.  Someone hearing it and trying to ascribe words to it could easily assume "what is" is what was said.

Comment: Thank for this explanation. I've uploaded the example from the movie [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B1TeD7LxKfCFbm1Sd1c4SG0yTTg/edit?usp=sharing). You'll notice that the subtitles say *What does...* while the actress clearly says *What is...*. I'm pretty sure that's the "sluring together" of the two words. Thanks again.