# How many allophones possible of phoneme /ə/ are there in American English?

Tags: american-english, dialects, phonology, stress, fast-speech-rules

I am an ESL student. I want to speak American English fluently.

Due to influence of my local dialect in my country, I only discover that there is [ə ɐ ɪə ɑ] doubtably according to my ear, and native American English speaker speak with allophone differently in their dialect, As in:

- Russia /ˈrʌʃə/ —>  [ˈɹɐʃɐ] [ˈɹɐʃə] [ˈɹɐʃɑ]
- Asia /ˈeɪʒə/ —> [ˈeɪʒɪə] [ˈeɪʒɑ] [ˈeɪʒɐ] [ˈeɪʒə]
- Comma /ˈkɑːmə/ —> [ˈkɑːmə] [ˈkɑːmɑ] [ˈkɑːmɐ]
- China /ˈtʃaɪnə/ —> [ˈtʃaɪnə] [ˈtʃaɪnɑ]  [ˈtʃaɪnɐ]
- Prussia /ˈprʌʃə/  —> [ˈprɐʃɑ] [ˈprɐʃɐ]

I think there are more allophones. Am I right? If so, please add more allophones and which is the most common one.

Comment: Do we really say  [ˈeɪʒɑ], [ˈkɑːmɑ], [ˈtʃaɪnɑ]? I'll agree that [ɐ] and [ə] are very common allophones of schwa in American English, but I have trouble believing that many people say these words with the vowel of *Arkansas* or *chihuahua*.

Comment: According to dictionaries, *Arkansas* is indeed [ˈɑːrkɑnsɔː] and *chihuahua* is [tʃɪˈwɑːwɑ]. I was thinking *Arkansas* ended with an /ɑ/, which I think is an uncommon (and maybe wrong) alternate pronunciation. But I don't believe many people use either of these vowels as an allophone of [ə]. (Although some people do use a /ə/ in *Chihuahua*.)

Comment: And [ɪə] is only an allophone of schwa in a few words like Asia or Appalachia that end in *ia*.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129033/discussion-between-ieatmy-pizza-and-peter-shor).

Comment: Vowel reduction is variable; *comma* [ˈkʰɔmʌ], *rabbit* ['ɻʷɛ̝ə̯bɨt] also occur. Related & possible dups: [1](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/105977), [2](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/428639), [3](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/258755), [4](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/244117), [5](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/78871), [6](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/112025), [7](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/362675), [8](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/404348), [9](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/484180), [10](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/408502).

Comment: Offsite links also related: [1](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.1177/1367006909103528), [2](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5533556/), [3](https://asa.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1121/1.401662), [4](http://web.mit.edu/flemming/www/paper/schwaphonetics.pdf).

Comment: @tchrist, thanks! Did [ʌ] you used represent open-mid back unrounded vowel or Near-open central vowel?

Comment: @IEatMyPizza [You’ll have to ask a Scot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_English_close_front_vowels#Weak_vowel_merger). You have to train yourself to unhear different phones, different pronunciations. You have to mentally envision only broad abstract phonemes; that's what native speakers do. Everything else is just allophonic variation from "somebody else's accent", and it doesn't count. We always know which thing was said no matter the actual realization phonetically, usually because these differences are too small to notice. **Listen for the stressed syllables *only***.

Comment: Ok. ONLY is /ˈəʊnli/.

Comment: VTC. This question is both lacking research and (posed as being) open-ended.